# Conversion of .osm file extension to .osm.pbf

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

I am trying to use osm2pgsql which requires me have a .pbf file extension. Is it possible to convert .osm file to .osm.pbf file?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

osm2pgsql can read `.osm` files directly. `.osm.pbf` is just a compressed `.osm` file (see [PBF Format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) in the OSM wiki).

If you still need to convert between those files for whatever reason then take a look at [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) (the fastest and more modern), [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) or [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert).